# Ruby/Poppler PDF Table of Contents/Index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, poppler

Have been trying to obtain the TOC/Index for PDF files using Ruby and Poppler. I would really appreciate any suggestions or hints in the right direction I am successful at getting the major Chapters, but not the sub headings under each chapter. ex

```
1.Chapter 1
  --Part of Chap1
  -- Part of Chap 1
2.Chapter 2
   -- Part of Chap2 
   -- Part of Chap2
```

I am able to obtain **Chapter 1** and **Chapter 2** but not the **part of Chap1/chap 2** when using ruby and poppler. I might be thinking  about this the wrong way, but from what I understood , if a child exist for `Poppler::IndexIter` , I would assume the same methods used to obtain Chapter 1 and Chapter 2 would work for the child as well, however this does not appear to be the case. Tried to use action.title on the child class, however it appears to be nil. The Pdf i am currently using shows up in all PDF readers with sub chapters.

http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Poppler%3A%3AIndexIter#open%3F

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rubygems"
require "poppler"


if ARGV.size < 1
  puts "usage: #{$0} input.pdf"
  exit(-1)
end

input = ARGV.shift
input_uri = "file://#{File.expand_path(input)}"

doc = Poppler::Document.new(input_uri)
indexer = Poppler::IndexIter.new(doc)
author = doc.n_pages

index = doc.index_iter
pages = doc.n_pages
#puts "  #{doc.metadata}\n"
puts "This is the number of pages  #{pages}\n"


#Prints out  Table of Contents each chater

def walk_index(indexer)
    indexer.each do |i|

    chaps =i.action.title
    puts chaps
    child = i.child

    workk_index(child) if child.nil? == false
    end
end

def work_index(child)
    #puts child
    child.each do |h|
        puts h.action.title 
    end
end

walk_index(indexer)
```

Comment: Well it appears that I am not the only one having this problem and it might be something thats wrong with Ruby/Poppler itself  -->http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3350148&group_id=53614&atid=470969